# Render Template according the option selected from a drop down

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to render a template according the option the user picks from a drop down, but unfortunately is not working for me. My code looks like this

```js
const beer = {
  name: 'Belgian Wit',
  brewery: `Steam Whistle Brewery`,
  keywords: ['pale', 'cloudy', 'spiced', 'crisp'],
  texto: 'hello'
};


function renderKeywords(keywords) {
  return `
    <select multiple="true">
        ${keywords.map(keyword => `<option>${keyword}</option>`)}
    </select>
  `;
}

function renderHtml(texto) {
  return `
     <input type="text" id="${texto}" value=""/>
  `;
}

function selectElement(elem) {
  if (elem.value === 'multiple') {
    document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = $ {
      renderKeywords(beer.keywords)
    };
  } else {
    document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = $ {
      renderHtml(beer.texto)
    };
  }
}

const markup = `
  <div class="beer">
      <h2>${beer.name}</h2>
      <p class="brewery">${beer.brewery}</p>
      <select onchange="selectElement(this)">
         <option>Select</option>
         <option value="multiple">Multiple</option>
         <option value="single">Single</option>
      </select> 
      <div id="p2"></div>
  </div>
`;

document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML = markup;
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a typo, mate. The lines `$ {renderKeywords(beer.keywords) }` and `$ { renderHtml(beer.texto) }` were throwing errors because you were trying to pass the `${}` from a Template literal to the `innerHTML` property, but without the backticks.

Though the backticks and brackets are not necessary as your `renderKeywords()` already returns a string.

```
...
  if (elem.value === 'multiple') {
    document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = $ {
      renderKeywords(beer.keywords)
    };
  } else {
    document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = $ {
      renderHtml(beer.texto)
    };
  }
...
```

```js
const beer = {
  name: 'Belgian Wit',
  brewery: `Steam Whistle Brewery`,
  keywords: ['pale', 'cloudy', 'spiced', 'crisp'],
  texto: 'hello'
};

function renderKeywords(keywords) {
  return `
    <select multiple="true">
        ${keywords.map(keyword => `<option>${keyword}</option>`)}
    </select>
  `;
}


function renderHtml(texto) {
  return `
     <input type="text" id="${texto}" value=""/>
  `;
}

function selectElement(elem) {
  if (elem.value === 'multiple') {
    document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = renderKeywords(beer.keywords);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = renderHtml(beer.texto);
  }
}

const markup = `
  <div class="beer">
      <h2>${beer.name}</h2>
      <p class="brewery">${beer.brewery}</p>
      <select onchange="selectElement(this)">
         <option>Select</option>
         <option value="multiple">Multiple</option>
         <option value="single">Single</option>
      </select> 
      <div id="p2"></div>
  </div>
`;

document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML = markup;
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</body>
```